# How can I make Listview in android like iPhone Tableview?

Tags: android, listview

Listview with empty cell, without adding blank object in Adapter (myAdapter.add("")).
I don't want that type of solution.
Is there any property or method which though we get this type of functionality.

### Iphone Image Tableview

[image: iphone tableview image with empty cell]

Answer (score 1):

You could set in the getCount method of the base adapter to some value, e.g 20. And then in the getView method in the first 4 items set the layout for those items...in the other items set a layout that is empty.

Comment: appreciate form your answer but it will be problematic while user click on empty cell, at that time I have check many condition. and it also not looking good for every resolution (HVGA, WVGA etc).

Comment: You could set in the list adapter for the empty items that they should not be clickable. And for the resoulution you could check what resolution your device is with the DisplayMetrics class and depending on this do what you wan't to do. I know that's a lot of work with the metrics :)